# How to get GeoJSON response in Django REST framework gis

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, geodjango, django-rest-framework-gis

I am trying to get GeoJSON response using django rest framework but facing issue

```
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

This is my code

```
class NewPark(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    geometry = models.GeometryField(srid=3857, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'new_park'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class NewParkSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NewPark
        geo_field = "geometry"
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'geometry')

class NewParkViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = NewPark.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

When i change serialize type to **'erializers.GeoModelSerializer'** then it is working, but i want GEOJSON response

I have searched about GeoFeatureModelSerializer but cannot find any example **geo_field = "geometry"**. All example are about  **geo_field = "point"**

Please help me to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might only have the above error in the browsable API, because the default djanog-rest-framework html template renderer does not work with the GeoJson format.

To test if that is the case, try to call your api endpoint requesting it in json format, i.e. `/api/newpark.json` or equivalently `/api/newpark?format=json`. This should show you geojson data, if it does your backend API is fine, and the problem is the browsable html form.

If you want a browsable API for your GeoJson endpoint, then you might need to change the html template used to render your API end point.